# Properties in Command Pattern

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, undo, command-pattern

How do we handle simple public property setters in Command Pattern to make them undoable? Do I need to create a separate command for every property?

### Details

My application (WPF/MVVM/C#) currently implements undo/redo functionality by maintaining a stack of "state snapshots". These snapshots are created upon every undoable action and pushed to the stack. While this approach has worked correctly so far, the size of undo stack keeps swelling, making application less responsive.

I'm now considering the prospects of moving to standard Command Pattern. Since I'm already using MVVM Light, I'd just extend `RelayCommand` to create `UndoableRelayCommand` and then push these to my undo stack instead of the snapshots. So far so good.

The problem however is that a lot of VM-level objects are bound directly to UI controls (through standard WPF `Binding`) and therefore get set directly without involving any `RelayCommand`. Setting of these properties needs to be an undoable action. How do I fit this requirement into standard Command Pattern, while keeping my Bindings intact?

Comment: How come the size of the stack makes the application less responsive? And how would using commands that adds to the stack fix this? Can't you just add to the stack from your data-bound property setters?

Comment: @mm8: As I said, I'm serializing the entire VM upon each action. Application memory starts shooting hundreds of MBs in a prolonged session. Using commands, each command will just store enough information to undo itself, which will drastically reduce undo stack's size (size in MBs, not the number of undo entries). Only problem is that of simple properties  that are bound directly to the UI elements.

Comment: Can't you call the appropriate command from the setter of the data-bound property?

Comment: @mm8. There is no command involved in these properties. These are directly bound to UI elements and therefore get updated automatically through `Binding`. Standard Command Pattern does not include any provision for such properties (IIRC).

Comment: So what is your question? If there is no command involved, there is obviously no command pattern to apply to these properties.

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise you to still copy values into the command, because otherwise older commands will go out of sync with the state of the binding at the moment when they happened.

I presume that you are already only taking the snapshot of the affected value, not the entire form (that would be a blunder).

I do not understand what does it mean that the application is becoming unresponsive. All operations on undo/redo stack should be `O(1)`. If your implementation is more complex than `O(1)` then that might be the direction for you to investigate before redesigning the mechanism.

Anyway, with the undo/redo stack, there is one practical trick usually applied in larger applications. Bound the size of the stack. With more items pushed, let it "forget" the oldest ones. Another practical trick also used around is to purge the stack every time the state is persisted, and only keep the last command to redo. Those are the performance tweaks I saw this far.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your input. *taking snapshot of the affected value* is not an option because so many of the actions in my application affect **multiple** properties of **multiple** objects (e.g. dock all selected objects to top). Since I'm currently not using Command Pattern, there is no way of keeping track of just the affected value. So the only way I'm left with is taking snapshot of entire VM on every undoable action (what you call blunder, lol). This is exactly why I'm looking to move to Command Pattern.